# Unable to run NoraUI mvn verify goal

Tags: java-17, noraui

We have taken back our test automations after a year leaving it unused.

Today, I Try to run them as usual (or at least as I remeber it)

```
mvn clean verify "-Dcucumber.options=--tags '@xxscenario'" -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -P scenarioInitiator,dev,xxProject,postIC,preIC
```

It might be linked to the fact that today I have jdk 17 installed, but i cannot run them :

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate public cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend(cucumber.runtime.io.ResourceLoader,io.cucumber.stepexpression.TypeRegistry) with [cucumber.runtime.io.MultiLoader@515ebef3, io.cucumb
er.stepexpression.TypeRegistry@545607f2]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: io.cucumber.core.backend.ObjectFactory: Provider cucumber.runtime.java.guice.impl.GuiceFactory could not be instantiated
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,
int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @7225790e
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatE
rror accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @7225790e
```

I've read some subjects about this but I'm quite unsure about the workarround to set up.

Thanks a lot.

EDIT :
Rollbacked my JDK to 11 and I no longer have this error. Could we have an update in ordrer to make it runnable with a java 17 JDK ? Thanks in advance !